# Python Selenium how to fill in many text boxes at once

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, bots, autofill

I am scripting a python autofill script using selenium and python 3.6. I want to fill in text input boxes as quickly as possible. right now I use:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById(--the elements ID--          
-).value='%s'" % ---what I want script to fill the box with---)
```

I repeat this line of code for each of the input text boxes of the website being autofilled. This is quick however it fills each text box one at a time. I want to fill all of the input boxes at once with different values similar to the chrome extension "autofill". All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) prepare a javascript file at local together with your auto script, define a function in it and accept an object which includes all fields value you want to set, in function body find element and set value.

```
function autofill(values) {
 document.querySelector("#username").value = values.username;
 document.querySelector("#city").value = values.city;
 ...
}
```

2) use driver.executeScript() to inset a script node into head node, and call the function.

```
var script = 'var script = document.createElement("script");' +
 'script.src=file:///<script file absolute path>; ' + 
 'document.head.appendChild(script);' +
 'autofill(arguments[0])';

driver.executeScript(script, fieldsValue);
```

Comment: Very very helpful. Solution for me was to write  "driver.execute_script( " then write each query selector of the page with a ";" in between. As for inputting values I just used %s. Made it slightly quicker with less code then creating a local js function. I did not realised you could use ";" to separate each input. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure i understand you correctly.

Do you want to fill all elements with  the same ID with the same text?

You can try to do it this way:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_id('your id here')
for element in elements:
    element.send_keys('---')
```

Comment: please check edits. I want to fill in all input textboxes of a site at once with different values. cheers